# Custom Form Element Factory - where are the options?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form, factory

I'm trying to create a custom form element, fundamentally everything works -- but I'd like to intake 'name' properly.  Let me explain:

```
use Application\Form\Element\Custom;

class CustomForm extends Form
{
     public function init(){
         $this->add([
            'name' => 'themagicname', 
            'type' => Custom::class,
         ]);
     }
}
```

I have a form that instantiates a Custom element, the custom element is mapped in my `module.config.php` as:

```
use Application\Form\Element\Custom;
use Application\Factory\Form\Element\CustomFactory;

return [
   //...
   'form_elements' => [
        'factories' => [
            Custom::class => CustomFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
   //...
];
```

The factory looks like this, and gets fired properly:

```
class CustomFactory implements Factory
{

    public function createService( ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator )
    {
        /**
         * @var \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository $userRepository
         * @var \Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterPluginManager $serviceLocator
         */


        // bunch of factory-ish things here

        return new Custom( 'helpppp', ... );
    }
}
```

Now the conundrum:  Where I wrote 'helpppp', one would ideally transport'themagicname' that was passed during creation at the Form level.  How does that config array, get ferried over to the factory? I've tried `MutableCreationOptionsInterface` but it doesn't seem to apply here.

Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean with 'at the form level'. You can add form elements to the form from within the *factory* using `$form->add(array(...))`, rather than on `init()`.

Comment: Did you find how to access custom form's parameters from within the factory ?